# linq on datarow to get index of specific item

Tags: linq, datatable, datarow

I have datatable which it first row is headers
I need specific column for this datatable according to the header

I know how to get the column if know its index.
The problem is how to get the index

```
Dim columnIndex as integer
Dim headerRow As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
Dim colHeader As string ="abc"
columnIndex=???
Dim result = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().[Select](Function(row) row(columnIndex)).Distinct().ToList()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use the dt.Rows.IndexOf

```
Dim ValueToSearch AS string = ...
columnIndex = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(of String)(colHeader) = ValueToSearch).Select(Function(x) dt.Rows.IndexOf(x)).SingleOrDefault()
```

The above will work if the where clause returns only one or zero rows. If this is not true then you may dismiss the SingleOrDefault and then loop through the results, ie:

```
columnIndex = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(of String)(colHeader) = ValueToSearch).Select(Function(x) dt.Rows.IndexOf(x))
For Each i in columnIndex
    Console.WriteLine("Value found in row with index " + i.ToString())
Next
```

Giannis